# Subtracting numbers in a column

Tags: bash

Inside a file I have a column with numbers with 10 elements. I want to subtract the 1st from the 3rd number, the 2nd from the 4th, the 3rd from the 5th, the 4th from the 6th, and so on till the 8th from the 10th.

For example:

```
10.3456
6.3452
11.2456
5.6666
10.5678
6.4568
14.7777
7.5434
16.5467
8.9999
```

and get a file with the subtraction

```
3rd-1st
4th-2nd
5th-3rd
6th-4th
7th-5th
8th-6th
9th-7th
10th-8th
```

Answer (score 4):

quick and dirty:

```
$  awk '{a[NR]=0+$0}END{for(i=3;i<=NR;i++)print a[i]-a[i-2]}' file
0.9
-0.6786
-0.6778
0.7902
4.2099
1.0866
1.769
1.4565
```

#### Update: came up with another funny way:

```
$ awk 'NF>1{print $1-$2}' <(paste  <(sed -n '3,$p' file) file)  
0.9
-0.6786
-0.6778
0.7902
4.2099
1.0866
1.769
1.4565
```

#### update2, make the result CSV:

```
kent$  awk '{a[NR]=0+$0}END{for(i=3;i<=NR;i++)
            printf "%s%s", a[i]-a[i-2],NR==i?RS:","}' file
0.9,-0.6786,-0.6778,0.7902,4.2099,1.0866,1.769,1.4565
```

Comment: Thank you @Kent ...if I want to save this data, in an row and not in column and separate by comma (,) how do you do that?

Comment: update3? `paste -d- <(tail -n +3 file) <(head -n -2 file) | bc | paste -sd,`

Comment: @kent I check update2 later, now my kid takes my time :) thank you, I check later

Comment: @kent I've checked updated2, it works well!, could you explain me the commands? I will appreciate it if you could.

Comment: @EnricAgudPique it save all lines in an array, and do the math calculation. for output, printf will let you control what kind of output format you want to have.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
#Create an array
mapfile -t lines < inputFile


output=()
for index in "${!lines[@]}"; do
# Check if the index + 2 exist
    if [[ ${lines[$(expr $index + 2)]} ]]; then
    #It does exist, do the math
        output+=("$(expr ${lines[$index]} + ${lines[$(expr $index + 2)]})")
    fi

done

printf "%s\n" "${output[@]}" > output
```

Answer (score 1):

perly dog

```
perl -ne '$a{$.}=$_;print $_-$a{$.-2}."\n" if $a{$.-2}' file
```

Makes an array
If a key of two lines before exists then print that line minus the value from array.

```
0.9
-0.6786
-0.6778
0.7902
4.2099
1.0866
1.769
1.4565
```

For in a row like asked for in Kents answer

```
perl -ne '$a{$.}=$_;print $_-$a{$.-2}.(eof()?"\n":",") if $a{$.-2}' file

0.9,-0.6786,-0.6778,0.7902,4.2099,1.0866,1.769,1.4565
```

Answer (score 0):

With awk, I'd write

```
awk -v ORS="" '
    {a=b; b=c; c=$0}                  # remember the last 3 lines
    NR >= 3 {print sep c-a; sep=","}  # print the difference
    END {print "\n"}                  # optional, add a trailing newline.
' file
```

Or let paste do the gruntwork

```
awk '{a=b;b=c;c=$0} NR >= 3 {print c-a}' file | paste -sd,
```